# How is the Normandy refueled?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've never bought fuel at a fuel depot, but I sometimes find the Normandy has returned to 1000 fuel.  I've found fuel a few times while scanning, but definitely not that much.  Are there other actions that cause the Normandy to refuel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Docking at the Citadel gives you a refueling. If you've ever gone to the Citadel, that'd be why you have your fuel back.

Comment: Really? Ha! Wasted those credits then! (Refueled as I was leaving a system *on my way back to the Citadel!*)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that!

Comment: That's what I suspected, but it is good to have confirmation!